# Proper solution of the limit of $\sin(x)/\tan(x)$ as $x \to 0$

Tags: limits, intuition

In one of my math book, I have a problem where I need to compute $\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{\sin(x)}{\tan(x)}}$

I came up with a solution that I am not able to write formally. The reasoning is the following :

- Take x as an angle of a right-angled triangle and define by "opp" the opposite side of the triangle, "adj" the adjacent side of the triangle, and "hyp" the hypothenuse of the triangle.
- $\frac{\sin(x)}{\tan(x)} = \frac{opp}{hyp}*\frac{adj}{opp} = \cos(x)$
- $\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{\sin(x)}{\tan(x)}} = \lim_{x\to0}{\cos(x)} = 1$

Is there any way to write this formally ?

Note that I am aware that I could also compute this limit by using the Taylor expansion of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$.

Comment: Can't you use the identity $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your solution boils down to the fact that $\tan=\frac{\sin}{\cos}$ (which is often taken as the definition). If that is not the definition you are starting with, what is the characterization of $\tan$ you are allowed to use?

Comment: This looks perfectly formal to me. By definition tan=sin/cos

Comment: It was only the way I wrote things that seemed not formal enough to me. Looking at the answer to this post, it looks like that's only my perception that was wrong. 
I did not start with the definition of $\tan(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$ but, if I am not mistaken, I think this definition is based on the exact thing that makes me uneasy in the way I wrote the first steps of the limit above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that $$\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$$

to get $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0} \cos(x)$$

Your reasoning is equivalent to the first formula.

Comment: Looks indeed better to me. Isn't this definition based on the "opp/hyp/adj" definition though ?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: we have $\frac{\sin(x)}{\tan(x)}=\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(x)} \cdot \cos(x)=\cos(x)$ and our searched limit is $1$ for $x$ tends to zero

Comment: why the $-1$? what is wrong?

Comment: For what I can infer, (1) it's the same answer than the one below, and (2) at the end of the day it boils down to knowing whether the OP is allowed to use this fact... (i.e., what is assumed about the definition of $\tan$)

Comment: one can also say that the solution above is the same as mine the definition of the $\tan(x)$ function is well known in my opinion